# SELECT TOP 1 GROUP IN TABLE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, sql-order-by

In ORD table,

```
ORD_CODE    PROD_CODE
200212013   66298
200212014   66298
200212006   66297
200212007   66296
200212012   66296
200211025   66295
200211026   66295
200211027   66295
200211028   66295
200211029   66295
200211030   66295
200211031   66295
200211032   66295
200211033   66295
200211034   66295
```

I want

```
200212014   66298
200212006   66297
200212012   66296
200211034   66295
```

I use `SELECT DISTINCT PROD_CODE, ORD_CODE FROM ORDERT`
but its not working.

And I use RankNo? but not working too.

Subquery, COUNT(), TOP 1, DESNSE_RANK, everything not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this while avoiding an explicit subquery is to use `TOP 1 WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES ORD_CODE, PROD_CODE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROD_CODE ORDER BY ORD_CODE DESC);
```

Answer (score 2):

If your dataset has just two columns, simple aggregation should be enough:

```
select min(ord_code) ord_code, prod_code
from mytable
group by prod_code
```

Answer (score 1):

[DEMO ON DB<>FIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ceb5679f2425d196041b83a4d0f127e)

You can use [ROW_NUMBER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)() to achieve it

```
;WITH cte_TempData as (
  SELECT ORD_CODE, PROD_CODE, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PROD_CODE ORDER BY ORD_CODE DESC) Row_Number
  FROM #TempTable
)
SELECT ORD_CODE, PROD_CODE
FROM cte_TempData
WHERE Row_Number = 1
```

**Output**

[image]